# Lines of code use smaller/different font if non-alphanumeric characters are the only thing on the line

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In VS 2013, I've noticed that lines of code show in a smaller/different font if it contains only non-alphanumeric characters (basically, punctuation and special characters only).  This is especially rough for me because, due to OCD being triggered, I now have to put text comments at the end of every line that contains only a curly brace to ensure that the font size matches all of the others.  This is really starting to affect my overall performance, so I am hoping that someone help me find out why this is happening and what can be done to fix it.

[image]

Comment: I would go through the list of fonts in the settings (Tools -> Options, Environment -> Fonts and Colors).  You can set a different font size for different types of text, and I wouldn't be surprised if you have some different values in there.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all text editor fonts are Consolas 10.  Find the display item that is different.

1. Open TOOLS (menu), Options... (item), Environment (tree), Fonts and Colors (item).
2. Select Show settings for: Text Editor
3. Select Display items: Auto Completed Brace
4. Keep pressing the down arrow key until you notice a the Size field as not 10.
5. Change the field to 10.

Alternatively, in the Fonts and Colors panel, you could click "Use Defaults" to reset all the fonts quickly, but you'd lose any customization that you added.